# Audio synthesizer that can perform seamless TTS editing for already spoken text

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, speech-synthesis, voice-recognition

In April 2016, Adobe reported about an experimental piece of software, [VoCo](https://theblog.adobe.com/lets-get-experimental-behind-the-adobe-max-sneaks/). Basically it's Photoshop for voices: you have a sound recording, but you're able to edit it like text, i.e. remove a word and replace it by another. In the link they descibe it as

> When recording voiceovers, dialogue, and narration, wouldn’t you love the option to edit or insert a few words without the hassle of recreating the recording environment or bringing the voiceover artist in for another session? #VoCo allows you to change words in a voiceover simply by typing new words. Have to hear it to believe it? Check out a live demo using a recording of Keegan-Michael Key’s voice.

And of course, they then [switch to a video (Youtube)](https://youtu.be/I3l4XLZ59iw?list=PLD8AMy73ZVxVLnQh5m-qK0efH3rKIYGx2), which can much better demonstrate its capability.

Sometimes, Open Source people are really clever and once the idea and concept is known, they rapidly adapt it and come up with a similar solution.

I'd like to know whether this particular text to speech roundtrip has been implemented in a gratis or open source way.

Required features:

- Import recorded voice (any common file format is ok, e.g. WAV or MP3)
- Voice recognition to transform the wave format into text
- Text editing / replacement
- TTS (text to speech), in order to change the recorded voice to match the new text
- Save the result (again, any common file format)

I can try it on Windows or Linux.

Comment: Would you mind removing the word "Adobe VoCo" from the title? Or at least write a title like "Sound editor to insert words into speech (Free alternative to Adobe VoCo)". Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul. Thanks. I have created https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/product-names-in-question-titles-alternative-to-titles